# Excel Using Data Model to supplement my tracking sheet

Tags: excel, database, vba, hana

I have a tracking sheet that I would like to have updated using an external database. The tracking sheet is just a table in Excel with several columns. Some columns are manual entries, notes and things. Some columns are linked to the values from our database based on the index value for each row.

I have to generate a search string for all the unique index values in my table, search my database, export those results to a `csv` file, dump that into a separate worksheet, and then link it back to my tracking table. I would like not to have to do that data dump every few days and just directly pull the data I need from the database.

My table columns looks something like below and has a few hundred rows. I track projects and keep some notes on to do items or just general reference.

```
Index | Manual Entry 1 | Manual Entry 2 | Database Param 1 (DB1) | Database Param 2(DB2)
```

My data sheet looks like this.

```
Index | DB1 | DB2
```

I can load my database into excel as a data model already. Depending on which one I pull, some of them have a few million rows so I cannot just load them directly into a table. I can't figure out how to query the data model for a specific parameter based on an index value. Today I used a macro to pull the DB1 and DB2 values from my data that I exported from the database.

Everything I looked up about data models and excel either results in pivot tables or reporting out numeric data. I found the `cubemember` and `cubevalue` functions but I couldn't get the expressions to give me a raw value based on the index. It was always just a count of values.

My sudo code today looks like this.

```
'loop through rows of indexes
   If DataIndex = TrackingIndex then
     'loop through columns of DB1,DB2,DB3...
       if DataDB# = TrackingDB# Then
        TrackingValue = DataValue
       end if
     next
   end if
 next
```

I just need to know what formula can `index(match())` into a database model? or what VBA function will allow me to load the data model into an array that i can loop through?

Or is there a better way to accomplish this all together?

Comment: Can't you just run an SQL query against your database and get the exact recordset you want?

Comment: I am not sure how SQL queries work but a brief search looks like that may be the answer. So the SQL query essentially filters the data model to only my relevant rows. Since it’s a smaller model I can then put that in a table and do my normal stuff that I do?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Bring only the data you need into Excel. SQL will allow you to fine-tune the dataset precisely as you need it. Then you can use Excel to analyze the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i finally figured this out. I didn't go through the true SQL route. I merged the help of these two articles.

https://radacad.com/dynamic-sql-using-power-query

https://eriksvensen.wordpress.com/2017/12/12/powerquery-filter-a-table-based-on-another-table-column-or-list-and-some-filter-ahas/

Basically, take your table that has all the look up values you want. Add that table to your data model. Edit it in power query per the first half of the first article above to reduce it down to just 1 list of unique values. I did this as a connection only because i did not need that list to actually exist anywhere.

Then load your connection to your database. Use the transform data button after you have selected your dataset. Follow the second article to filter it in power query based on the first table of unique values. It requires using the GUI filter commands for any random value. Then using the advanced editor, modifying that filter command to use your first table of values as the filter. Then load it to a table and do whatever index/match, vlookup, or macro processing you want!